# SQL Servr : how to use a lot of WHERE and AND statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

Tablet:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+
| DataID | ColD | ColS | Col3 |Col4  |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
|      1 | A    | E    | Y    |  Z   |  
|      2 | B    | F    | Y    |  Z   |      
|      3 | C    | G    | Y    |  Z   |   
|      4 | B    | E    | Y    |  Z   |     
|      5 | T    | G    | Y    |  Z   | 
+--------+------+------+------+------+
```

My question is: how do I get all columns where

```
    ColD = A OR B 
    AND ColS = E OR F 
    OR ColD = C 
    AND ColS = 'G' 
    AND col3 = 'Y' 
    AND col4 = 'Z'
```

The Solution:

```
SELECT *
WHERE   (ColD IN ( 'A', 'B') 
                 AND ColS IN ( 'E', 'F' ) 
                 AND Col3 = 'Y' 
                 AND Col4 = 'Z')
              OR (ColD = 'C'
                 AND ColS = 'G' 
                 AND Col3 = 'Y' 
                 AND Col4 = 'Z')
```

Question: If you want to know how to get the above solution, how would you ask it so it is easier to understand?

Thanks all for help.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I can't understand your question, can you word it a little clearer?

Comment: Reading your text: `select * from data where (ColD = A and ColS in (E, F) ) and ColD = B...` <= This already fails, because ColD can't be "A", and at the same time, also "B".  SUGGESTION: Try writing down your filter as a set of "and" and "or" expressions *without* using "where" more than once and *without" using "with" at all.  Use parenthesis liberally.  Update your post.

Comment: You're making progress with your third example. Good!  You're on the right track!  CURRENT PROBLEM: `AND (ColS = 'E' OR ColS = 'F')` and `AND (ColS = 'G')` are *mutually exclusive*.   They are a [contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction).  So the expression will always evaluate to "false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, this is a pretty basic logical construction. The key is to separate alternative conditions using `or`.

The list you've provided translate pretty directly like this (with a lot of assumptions):

```
WHERE  ( cold = 'A' 
         AND cols IN ( 'E', 'F' ) ) 
        OR ( cold = 'B' 
             AND cols IN ( 'F', 'E' ) ) 
        OR ( cold = 'C' 
             AND cols = 'G' 
             AND col3 = 'Y' 
             AND col4 = 'Z' )
```

However, looking at the actual conditions, it can be simplified a little:

```
WHERE  ( cold IN ( 'A', 'B' ) 
         AND cols IN ( 'E', 'F' ) ) 
        OR ( cold = 'C' 
             AND cols = 'G' 
             AND col3 = 'Y' 
             AND col4 = 'Z' )
```

---

As paulsm4 has suggested, you need a lot more parenthesis. The way your question is worded now (without parenthesis), we can't tell what order to evaluate the conditions in (which is important when you're mixing `and` and `or`). If we can't figure out the appropriate order, then the software certainly can't. Putting parenthesis around individual operations (i.e. `(t.col3 = 'Y')`) is pointless; it does nothing to indicate the order that you require.

Based on your latest edit, it seems like maybe you want to always enforce the conditions `col3 = 'Y' AND col4 = 'Z'`. If that's the case, then the conditions might look like this:

```
WHERE  ( ( cold IN ( 'A', 'B' ) 
           AND cols IN ( 'E', 'F' ) ) 
          OR ( cold = 'C' 
               AND cols = 'G' ) ) 
       AND col3 = 'Y' 
       AND col4 = 'Z'
```

Comment: Your above query is getting the correct cold and cols but the Col3 and Col4 are showing other values (not all Y for col3 and not all Z for col 4)

Comment: @Alkippe Nikephoros - Please update your post - please "word it a little clearer".  Just use "where" (one time only), "and", "or", "in(...)" and parenthesis.  In doing so - you'll probably answer your own question ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 so I can make it easier next time, how would you make the question clearer based on the answer? -Allan Your above query gets the results I wanted and is a simplified version of what I end up getting working based on your original query. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Alkippe Nikephoros: fair question.  The original post was hopelessly ambiguous: "`My question is: how do I get all columns where ColD = A with ColS = E or F where ColD = B with ColS = F or E where ColD = C with ColS = G and col3 = Y and col4 = Z`".  That could have broken down several different ways.  Both Allan and Stidgen took guesses at what you meant - and it sounds like those guesses were pretty accurate :)  Book recommendation: [SQL Queries for Mere Mortals](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Queries-Mere-Mortals-Manipulation/dp/0321444434).  It's really a great tutorial on "thinking in SQL".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE (colD = 'A' OR colD = 'B') AND (colS = 'E' or colS = 'F') 
OR (colD = 'C' AND colS = 'G' AND col3 = 'Y' AND col4 = 'Z')
```

works with the sample data provided, giving this result:

```
DataID    colD    colS    col3    col4
   1        A       E      Y       Z
   2        B       F      Y       Z
   3        C       G      Y       Z
   4        B       E      Y       Z
```

as others have noted, the key is to translate what you want into boolean terms.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work because I did not specify what order I wanted the conditions to be evaluated. Thank you for your help anyways